# Is there a limit to displaying columns for results in HUE?

Tags: hive, hue

I only get the first 10 columns displayed in results in HUE, and the next columns greyed out. Is this an expected behavior in HUE interface ? If so, is there a configuration to override this ?

Thanks,
Parag

Checked hue.ini configuration file to see if there is a config to override this.